# how to debug delete button action in Lightswitch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am supposed to find a bug  in Lightswitch C# application written in VS2012
which causes application to hung when delete button is clicked. I am new to LS
and have problem figuring out how to find the internal code is executed when that
button is selected. Even when I try to override action of this button debugger doesn't stop there. Debugging just my code is turned off, on screen data binding I see some name I cannot find in the code. Anybody here has some experience with lightswitch to point me to right direction?  thanks

Comment: Is it a Desktop or Html application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightswitch HTML uses JavaScript for the code behind, not C#.  An example of a typical LS delete command:

```
screen.Items.deleteSelected();
```

Debugging can be a bitch at times, often i find i have to place breakpoints *AFTER* running the application.  Alternatively, you could use a crude debugging method and insert a bunch of alert() methods in the JavaScript.  It's not pretty, but it's effective.

*Note: The delete code could be calling a WebAPI web service, or running SQL against a database.  In both these scenarios you will need to separately debug these.*

Comment: thanks, is that javascript code hidden somewhere? search for delete method doesn't fine it. how about intellitrace? will it work with this?

Comment: The JavaScript isn't hidden.  There should be an filename.lsml.js file associated with every filename.lsml file.  IntelliTrace does work with LightSwitch.