# Execute SQL Delete from LightSwitch C# button

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-lightswitch

hopefully a straight forward one here..

I have a Visual Studio LightSwitch HTML Client application which uses two Views as its data sources.

> Within the application I want to have a Delete button which executes a SQL query, deleting the record from a table which has a matching ID to the one currently selected within the app.

I found this handy [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635144.aspx) which seems straight forward, but when I try to implement it I'm receiving intellisense errors.  I'm a complete novice in C# so I don't have much in my arsenal to trouble shoot this with.

> MSDC has this quote
>
> 4.In the Screen Designer, open the shortcut menu for the button node, and then choose Edit Execute Code.
>
> 5.Add code that resembles the following example:

```
partial void UpdateEmployeeInfo_Execute()
{
    DataWorkspace dataWorkspace = new DataWorkspace();
    Employee employee = this.Employees.SelectedItem;

    UpdatePersonalInfoOperation operation = 
        dataWorkspace.ApplicationData.UpdateEmployeePersonalInfoOperations.AddNew();
    operation.EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID;
    operation.NationalIDNumber = employee.NationalIDNumber;
    operation.BirthDate = employee.BirthDate;
    operation.MaritalStatus = employee.MaritalStatus;
    operation.Gender = employee.Gender;

    dataWorkspace.ApplicationData.SaveChanges();
}
```

My confusion is that when you choose to EDIT EXECUTE CODE it automatically generates function tags:

```
myapp.ViewRecordDetails.DeleteRecord_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.

};
```

> Should the MSDN code go within that function, or am I replacing the default entirely?

When inserting the code into the auto generated tags without the partial void declaration, I get errors on dataWorkspace, employee and operation saying `Expected';'`
If I stick the whole unaltered MSDN code within the tags or do the MSDN tags without the auto-generated tags, I also get the same error on the word void

All help appreciated.  I haven't even gotten to structuring my query and establishing the connection.. one thing at a time

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not using the HTML Client?

Comment: I AM using an HTML client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightswitch HTML uses JavaScript for the code behind, not C#. An example of a typical LS delete command:

```
screen.Items.deleteSelected();
```

In your case:

```
myapp.ViewRecordDetails.DeleteRecord_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    screen.Items.deleteSelected();
};
```

I've answered a similar question here: [how to debug delete button action in Lightswitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928426/how-to-debug-delete-button-action-in-lightswitch)

Comment: Wow you're right, I assumed it was C# since it's a "LightSwitch HTML Application with Type of Visual C#"

This changes everything and explains why the C# wasn't working.

So that said, I want to delete the record from a table which is not currently in my solution. I thought this could be done with a SQL command, but should I link it to the VIEWS which I am currently using and then delete it within the application, rather than an external SQL command?

Comment: There are many ways you could achieve this.  Personally, i'd use a WebAPI web service, call it using a jQuery AJAX Get or Post request from within the javascript, and perform the delete using SQL or Entity Framework.

Comment: Thank you I will give that a shot